# How to pass an imported function(not method) as a prop

Tags: vue.js

when passing dynamic props, we use : or v-bind. However, any variables within these v-binds refers to the data stored within the component rather than within the script (passes on data in the component that can be referenced using "this.data".

However, that is not what I want to do in this case, I want to pass down an imported function into a prop, which is referenced within the component without a "this." in front of the function. When I try to pass it on as a prop, it says "functionName" is defined but never used", how do you go about passing on imported functions as dynamic props? See the code below for more details.

```
<template>
    <componentName 
        :propName="functionName"
    />
</template>

<script>
import {functionName} from "./helperFunctions.js"
export default {
    components: {componentName}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not passing as an event? however you can pass this function as a `prop` via `getters`:

```
<template>
  <componentName 
    :propName="myFuncProp"
  />
</template>
<script>
import {functionName} from "./helperFunctions.js"
export default {
  components: {componentName},
  computed: {
    myFuncProp () {
      return functionName
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While emiting an event works, the reason why I didn't do that is because in my case, it doesn't make sense for it to be passed back to the parent as an event as the only purpose of the parent in my case is a page which holds child components, so I don't want the parent to be doing anything except for specifying the props used in components. 

Regarding your code, that's helpful and thank you for that. Could I also ask why you used a computed property rather than a method?